# Show dialog while processing data

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to show a loading dialog when I'm doing a UI blocking task so I did this :

```cs
public void RetrievePosteInformations(string posteNumber)
{
    ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

    //try to show dialog on UI here
    RecherchePosteDialog recherchePosteDialog = new RecherchePosteDialog();
    _= recherchePosteDialog.ShowAsync();

    //UI blocking task
    foreach(KeyValuePair<int,string> keyval in filepaths)
    {
        retrieveCSVInfo(keyval.Value, posteNumber, keyval.Key);
    }

    //after task hiding the dialog again
    recherchePosteDialog.Hide();
}
```

But here the `Dialog` is not showing at all. I don't want to use an `await` statement because the program would keep stuck at `await recherchePosteDialog.ShowAsync()`.

I only want to show it asynchronously and hide it when the task is finished.

Comment: Wouldn't `LoadingIndicator` do the job?

Comment: What do you mean ? Like a `ProgressRing` where I set its visibility ?

Comment: Do you have to show a dialog ? or is showing a `ProgressRing` with a background covering up the content (to prevent user interaction) enough ?

Comment: Did you see [Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/loading) control?

Comment: No, but that's interesting, will check it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try running it in a thread with a ManualResetEvent.

When you call

> RetrieveWait.Set();

the dialog gets hidden.

---

Example:

```
private static ManualResetEvent RetrieveWait = new ManualResetEvent(false);

Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
() =>
{
    RecherchePosteDialog recherchePosteDialog = new RecherchePosteDialog();
    recherchePosteDialog.ShowAsync();

    RetrieveWait.WaitOne()
    recherchePosteDialog.Hide();
});
```